# Why is my link broken? Bash

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

I am trying to link files in a while loop for my script but just the simple linking code itself creates a broken link.

The directory structure is this:

```
main/working/script.sh
main/working/dir
main/shared/default/some_files
```

My script has this code:

```
ln -s ../shared/default/* dir
```

This creates broken link. I can make the link not broken if I go inside the directory of main/working/dir and use `ln -s ../../shared/default/* .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you link to a relative path; Inside your script go to main/working/:

```
cd main/working/
ln -s ../shared/default/* dir
```

either use the absolute path:

```
ln -s /absolute/path/to/shared/default/* dir
```

you might even [deduce the path where your script is located](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/2082964) and use that path:

```
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
ln -s $DIR/../../shared/default/* dir
```

**edit**: bash cannot expand the `*` if you are not at the right directory, so you can work around that to temporarily change directories:

```
# go to dir to make correct relative links
cd dir
ln -s $DIR/../../shared/default/* ./
cd ..
```

Comment: is there another way on linking it without using the absolute path?

Comment: I gave you three possibilities; the first is relative, second absolute, third is a mix of both: relative to the place where your script is located...

Comment: The first option you gave was the code I used and it gives broken links. The third option though is too long.

Comment: your link is broken because you are not located in the correct directory; that's why you need to go to your working directory

Comment: remark the line just before the one you used: `cd main/working` (note that you could use an absolute directory too here: `cd /path/to/main/working`

Comment: My script.sh now contains this
`cd main/working`
`ln -s ../shared/default/* dir` and it says `No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82056/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-gibs).